Solving differential equation using opamps
I have a first order differential equation with initial value problem:
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} =\frac{a}{b} \cdot x(t) - c \cdot y(t) $$
with initial values of $$ y(0) = (\frac{a}{b} \cdot c) \cdot x(0) $$
The value of a=8, b=.02 and c=.01, x(0)=5.
Now I need to implement this equation using opamps with appropriate scaling to prevent saturation. x(t) varies from 0-10V and I expect y(t) should be in same range. I have looked up in web, but no one solves with initial value problem. Moreover, I am unclear as how to charge the capacitor for the initial value.

Start by editing your question to show a circuit that integrates this equation with initial values set to zero. Then we can help you modify it to preset the initial values. You should look at existing schematics of the many analog computers that exist out there. Some are made even today - see "The Analog Thing", or any of the older "big brand" systems from the op-amp era. You have "looked up in the web", but there won't be anything for you to copy. You have to learn some analog computing first by investigating prior designs - actual products that were sold and used for this work.

Post-vacuum-tube analog computing used +/-10V signal range, since that uses the dynamic range of early transistor and IC op-amps well with +/-15V supplies (for ICs) or +/-18V to +/-25V for discrete transistor designs. A unipolar 0-10V range will require a virtual ground, and that complicates things.

I have upvoted the question to encourage you, since the question has potential. But this is clearly a homework problem and you must do some work first. A circuit that can integrate this equation starting at arbitrary initial condition is for you to design. You say that your problem is setting initial conditions - we need to see the circuit you want to set those conditions on first. Please edit the question and add these details in a timely manner. Do not respond with clarifications via comments - it's the question that's deficient and has to be improved.

Since it would be a fairly simple circuit, you can probably design and simulate it using CircuitLab built into this site - but it's hard for novices to know what's a reasonable simulator behavior and what is "garbage in, garbage out". Start from a simple integrator, add feedback, and work from there.

CircuitLab is garbage and where is the initial condition feature ?  Falstad.com is simple and better and you can edit initial voltage and plot anything or everything.  w for wire, c for cap, r for resistor etc. https://tinyurl.com/275hrksc  When the integrator output defines X the inverting input defines -dX/dt .

I simulated in matlab/simulink . I first converted the equation with laplace transform and  added suitable blocks in simulink. It works. I only need help in realizing this circuit in analog domain with appropriate scaling. I did search some reference designs on web, but if I could get specific help for this particular problem., it would be great

Should read https://the-analog-thing.org/THAT_First_Steps.pdf and this https://courses.grainger.illinois.edu/ece486/sp2020/laboratory/docs/lab1/analog_computer_manual.pdf
